# Unresolved reference: getIntentSender / While trying to obtain phone number in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, google-identity

I am trying to obtain phone number(s) in Jetpack compose following [Googles Phone Number Hint Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/phone-number-hint/android#kotlin_1). But I am stuck in a problem where it says: `getIntentSender()` is unresolved in `request: GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest`.

I am also getting another error on `addOnFailureListener`

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
 OnFailureListener
Found:
 Int
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PhoneNumberConsent() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val request = GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build()

    val phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    ) {
        try {
            val phoneNumber =
                Identity.getSignInClient(context)
                    .getPhoneNumberFromIntent(it.data)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Phone Number Hint failed")
        }

    }

    Identity.getSignInClient(context)
        .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
        .addOnSuccessListener(
            try {
                phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher.launch(request.getIntentSender())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Launching the PendingIntent failed")
            } as OnSuccessListener<in PendingIntent>
        )
        .addOnFailureListener(
            Log.e(TAG, "Phone Number Hint failed")
        )
}
```

Comment: Where is this code comes from? `as OnSuccessListener` cannot work - you're trying to cast `Unit` to listener.

Comment: @PylypDukhov this code is from [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/phone-number-hint/android#kotlin_1) Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you solve addOnFailureListener No phone number is found on this device error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addOnSuccessListener` accepts a listener, which can be passed as trailing closure.

Result passed to this listener is a pending intent which has `intentSender` property, and it can be used to create `IntentSenderRequest`.

Here's a working example:

```
val context = LocalContext.current

val request = GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build()

val phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
) {
    try {
        val phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(context)
                .getPhoneNumberFromIntent(it.data)
        println("phoneNumber $phoneNumber")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Phone Number Hint failed")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}

Button(onClick = {
    Identity.getSignInClient(context)
        .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
        .addOnSuccessListener { pendingIntent ->
            try {
                phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher.launch(
                    IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                        pendingIntent.intentSender
                    ).build()
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Launching the PendingIntent failed")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            println("addOnFailureListener $it")
        }
}) {

}
```

If you need to run it immediately after the view appears, use `LaunchedEffect` instead of `Button.onClick`. Your current approach contradicts one of the basic rules of Compose, which is that composable functions must be free of side-effects. Read more in [thinking in compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model)

Comment: First of all, Thank you a ton for investing time on my problem :) Does it print the phone number for you? I have tested on a real device, with `phoneNumber` being a value to a `Text`. It didn't show anything. Then I tested on an emulator where in the run console I can see this message: 
`I/System.out: addOnFailureListener com.google.android.gms.common.api.UnsupportedApiCallException: Missing Feature{name=auth_api_credentials_get_phone_number_hint_intent, version=3}`

Comment: @enoshy yes, it prints to me on a real device. You can't see a log or `Text` on the screen?

Comment: no! I assigned the value to a `Text` via state but it's not showing. Let me try for some time and I will be back. Thanks again!!

Comment: It prints: `No phone number is found on this device` in addOnFailureListener.

Comment: @enoshy on a real device, right? And your sim card is installed? Could you verify any other app, like some messenger can retrieve it?

Comment: Yes, on a real device! I have 2 sims installed. How do I verify any other app? sorry if it sounds dumb

Comment: @enoshy just download Telegram, go to register page and check wether you have to enter the phone number manually or it can suggest it for you

Comment: I had to type in manually!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245054/discussion-between-enoshy-and-pylyp-dukhov).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest) there is no `getIntentSender()` method in `GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest` class. Maybe there is a typo in the tutorial you are following, try to use `result` instead of `request`:

```
Identity.getSignInClient(context)
    .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        try {
            phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher.launch(result.intentSender.sendIntent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Launching the PendingIntent failed")
        } as OnSuccessListener<in PendingIntent>
    }
    .addOnFailureListener(
        Log.e(TAG, "Phone Number Hint failed")
    )
```

Comment: The first error message I got: `Type mismatch.
Required:
Intent!
Found:
GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest`

Then I tried to cast it as an `Intent` like this: `request as Intent` but now the app crashes.

Comment: please see my edited answer, using `result` object.

Comment: Hi! It was close! But Now I get this: `Type mismatch.
Required:
Intent!
Found:
IntentSender`

Then I tried to cast `result.intentSender as Intent` but now the app doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try to use `result.pendingIntent.intentSender`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Or `result.getData()`, or try to find another property of type `Intent` in the `result` object, there is a really bad documentation on this.

Comment: Hi, Looks like result object only has `intentSender` in the context of this problem. `intentSender` has `sendIntent` but I don't think it isn't helping. Looks like Google is busy with flutter and fuchsia.

Comment: `result.intentSender.sendIntent ` - maybe that's what will work.

Comment: it says `sendIntent` is a method that requires me to pass 5 mandatory arguments, only the `context` argument is known to me. I am very new to android dev, so I apologize for prolonging this thread. Also, Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: I would suggest also to check `request` object, maybe it has some properties of type `Intent` that can be used. Or maybe you need to update the version of the library you use, do you use the latest version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245053/discussion-between-enoshy-and-bigst).